# How to make a stopwatch timer

Tags: integrated-circuit, timer

I want to make a simple stopwatch timer using simple materials such as a breadboard, a couple of IC's (integrated circuits), wires, resistors, capacitors and transistors. Is it possible without doing some software programming?

EDIT: Can I use CD4511BE IC chip or CD4001BE IC chip??

Comment: Yes, but we need some more info: what precision do you want to achieve and how would you like the output to be. You are asking for a full design though, do not expect much help. You should also show some effort on your side, search the net, there are solutions to your problem laying around

Comment: Sure, it's possible, but the question as stated is far too broad to answer here. You'll have to come up with a design and ask specific questions about any points on which you get stuck.

Comment: Sure, if one of those ICs is a stopwatch IC (probably a mask-programmed micro controller) or an FPGA (in the latter case you'd be doing hardware programming, in Verilog or VHDL, most likely). You'd need a breakout board too as the packages are probably SMT.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.electronicsforu.com/electronicsforu/circuitarchives/view_article.asp?sno=253&article_type=1&id=332&tt=unhot)

Comment: @WarrenHill: There's nothing new under the sun! I built a circuit almost exactly like that about 40 years ago. Mine wasn't a stopwatch; it was a digital tachometer for automobile engines. I recycled the display and case from a calculator to hold it.

Answer (score 4):

A stopwatch is a simple device, conceptually. It just comprises an oscillator, a counter and a display of some sort. Controls are provided to start and stop the counting and to reset the counter. Here's a block diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkmflP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The oscillator `CLK1` determines the resolution and accuracy of the stopwatch. It could be anything from a 555 running at 1 Hz to a crystal oscillator with a prescaler at its output.

`LTCH1` is a simple set-reset flip-flop that debounces the Start and Stop buttons and controls whether or not clock pulses reach the counter.

The number of bits in the counter `U1` determine how high you can count. This could be a binary counter, a series of BCD counters, or a more complicated arrangement that counts hours, minutes and seconds directly.

`U2` is one or more chips that convert whatever the output of the counter is into signals that can drive the display, and `U3` is the display itself, which could be anything from individual LEDs to a set of 7-segment numerical displays, to a full alphanumeric display.

The point is, if you just want to demonstrate the concept on a breadboard, this could be very simple indeed: Use a 555 for the clock, a quad NAND gate chip for LTCH1 and AND1, and a 4- or 8-bit binary counter for U1. Just connect LEDs (with resistors) directly to its outputs to see the counting.

Answer (score 1):

Before this question gets closed you might want to think about what's involved in such a circuit.

[image]

You'll need some form of clock circuit producing regular (accurate) pulses.

Then you'll need some way of 'gating' these pulses so you'll need a start and stop system (I've shown this as an S-R type flip flop controlling an AND gate).

Then the pulses (ticks) need to be counted so you'll need a counter type circuit.

Then you'll need to get this 'count' to some form of display so you'll need to go through a decoder.

Then lets not forget we need to be able to reset the count ready to start again.

**AND** that's why you buy a chip that's designed to do all of this or use a micro that can be easily programmed to do this at a fraction of the cost of using discrete components.